# Why does element take up the whole viewport height even though I didn't set it anywhere in the code

Tags: html, css, height

I have this

`stats`

class in html which is the direct child of the

`body`

```
   <section class="stats">
      <div class="container">
        <h3 class="stats-heading text-center my-1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In, sit.
        </h3>
        <div class="grid grid-3 text-center my-4">
          <div>
            <i class="fas fa-server fa-3x"></i>
            <h3>1,0102,394</h3>
            <p class="text-secondary">Deployment</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <i class="fas fa-upload fa-3x"></i>
            <h3>1,0102,394</h3>
            <p class="text-secondary">Published</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <i class="fas fa-project-diagram fa-3x"></i>
            <h3>1,0102,394</h3>
            <p class="text-secondary">Projects</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

and css rules applied for it.

```
.stats {
padding-top: 10rem;
}
```

```
.container {
max-width: 110rem;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: auto;
padding: 0 4rem;
}
```

```
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
gap: 2rem;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
}
```

```
.grid-3 {
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```
.text-center {
text-align: center;
}
```

```
.my-4 {
margin: 3rem 0;
}
```

The section displayed in the full height of the viewport and the it seems that

```
height: 100%
```

in

```
.grid
```

was the cause.

But from what I have researched, when the

```
height: 100%
```

is set to an element and none of its ancestors have explicit height set for them, the height of the element should be the height of its content. Can any please explain the mechanism behind this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not taking full height, check the screenshot below
[image: screenshort]

```
.stats {
padding-top: 10rem;
}
```

stats class is adding padding-top to your element, that's why it's pushing 10rem below from the top. if you remove the class it will look like the below screenshot here is the link for [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-cache-r5pgej?file=/index.html)
[image: after removing stats class]